# String attribute in class that can only assign to specific values

Tags: java, string, class, oop

I remember that there is a data structure that guarantees that a certain string can only receive specific values, it works like an interface or something. I don't remember exactly the name of this data structure and couldn't find it easily.

Let me try to explain the context.

Let's say I've got a class called Foo with the parameter position.

```
class Foo {
   public static final String TOP = "TOP";
   public static final String BOTTOM = "BOTTOM";
   public static final String MIDDLE = "MIDDLE";

   private String position;

   Foo(String position){
        this.position = position;
   }
}
```

If I assign to position the values TOP, BOTTOM or Middle, position is going to accept. If I assign another value it will throw an exception.

```
new Foo(Foo.TOP)         // OK
new Foo(Foo.MIDDLE)      // OK
new Foo(Foo.BOTTOM)      // OK
new Foo("anystring")     // Throws Exception.
```

I know I could do a simple if else or switch and throw an exception, but I'd like to find this specific data structure.

Comment: I think you are looking for an [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: Right on the spot, thank you Mate

Comment: To be clear, an enum is not a string.

Comment: Like I said: "data structure". Just used string to exemplify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use enum for this to solve at that way.

```
class Foo {
   public static enum Position {TOP, BOTTOM, MIDDLE};

   private Position position;

   Foo(String position){
        this.position = Position.valueOf(position);
   }
}
```

But keep in mind: enum is not a `String`. But on enum you can call `toString()`, and also can parse a `String` to `enum`, like I did.

Comment: One small suggestion here is also to make `position` final as the object is immutable, but can still be changed via reflection :)

Comment: @YonatanKarp-Rudin `final` and immutable are two different things. For example, you may want to create a `Foo` object with a `position`, but then later change the `position` to a different value., say with a `setPosition()` method. If so, `position` should not be `final`.

Comment: That was my point, as there’s no setter for position it is immutable